# Did St. Augustine say God was busy preparing hell for people who ask about what was He doing before creation?

Tags: religion, quotes

Referring to [this quote](http://www.antievolution.org/features/evohumor/quote.html):

> He was busy creating hell for people who ask such questions.  -- St.
>   Augustine(in reply to "What was God doing before creation?")

Did St. Augustine actually say that?

Comment: There's also http://christianity.stackexchange.com/ if you didn't know about it. There, you can probably get better answers regarding context and meaning.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is part of Book 11, Chapter 12 of the *Confessions of St Augustine*.  Augustine said he would not say this, but said that somebody else had.  [In one translation](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/110111.htm):

> Behold, I answer to him who asks, "What was God doing before He made
>   heaven and earth?" I answer not, as a certain person is reported to
>   have done facetiously (avoiding the pressure of the question), "He was
>   preparing hell," says he, "for those who pry into mysteries." It is
>   one thing to perceive, another to laugh—these things I answer not. For
>   more willingly would I have answered, "I know not what I know not,"
>   than that I should make him a laughing-stock who asks deep things, and
>   gain praise as one who answers false things. But I say that Thou, our
>   God, art the Creator of every creature; and if by the term "heaven and
>   earth" every creature is understood, I boldly say, "That before God
>   made heaven and earth, He made not anything. For if He did, what did
>   He make unless the creature?" And would that I knew whatever I desire
>   to know to my advantage, as I know that no creature was made before
>   any creature was made.